# value does not fall within the expected range when moving datagridview data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagridview, oracle11g, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to move data from datagridview to Oracle Database. The datagridview dataset is filled with values from access database table which has 13 columns each with different data type. I have two buttons, one for filling the datagridview "works fine" and the the other button which the following code is related to which is supposed to move data from the datagridview to the Oracle database.
please note that I have tried this code previously from simple table that only contains number but when I try to execute this could the exception: "Value does not fall within the expected range" keeps popping up.
Pleaase Help me. I'm doing this for an assignment!! Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnOra = new OracleConnection(oradb);
        ConnOra.Open();
        String OraQuery = "Insert into availability(availid, nurseid, a_Date, a_start, a_end, anyearly, anymiddle, anylate, anynight, allocated, towhat, status, anyw, anyx, anyy, anyz) values (:availid, :nurseid, to_char(to_date(:a_date,'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_char(to_date(:a_start,'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_char(to_date(:a_end,'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), :anyearly, :anymiddle, :anylate, :anynight, :allocated, :towhat, :status, :anyw, :anyx, :anyy, :anyz)";
        try
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(OraQuery, ConnOra))
            {


                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                {

                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {


                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":availid", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["availid"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":nurseid", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["nurseid"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":a_Date", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["date"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":a_start", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["start"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":a_end", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["end"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":anyearly", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["anyearly"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":anymiddle", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["anymiddle"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":anylate", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["anylate"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":anynight", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["anynight"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":allocated", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["allocated"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":towhat", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["towhat"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":status", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["status"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":anyw", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["anyw"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":anyx", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["anyx"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":anyy", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["anyy"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":anyz", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["anyz"].Value));

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();


                    }
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Success");
                ConnOra.Close();
                ConnOra.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

    }
```

Comment: which line is giving you error?

Comment: Hello Ehsan, It doesn't say. how can I trace this error?

Comment: it is throwing an exception right? On which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: It does throw the exception but doesn't tell me which line!

Comment: Exception will contain line number

Comment: Better post exception stacktrace

Comment: Sriram, I have done what you suggested and here's what I get: at oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter..ctor(String parameterName, Object obj)
at my_project_name.Form1.button3_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Ehsan the line is this                     cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":a_end", dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["end"].Value)); sorry for not clearing

Comment: I can't seem to know why this line specifically!!